# How to improve a simple figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I have the following code for a figure and I'm quite satisfied with the result. Since I'm a novice in using tikz to make figures, I'd like some feedback on how this code could be improved. Particularly the use of the for loops and naming of the nodes.

The point is that I'll draw a second figure, very similar to this one, but with different lengths between the balls (shorter on the left side and longer on the right side). That's why the positions are negative in the x direction since the second figure will be located on the positive side.

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[oxygen/.style = {inner sep=2mm, draw=gray!80,fill=gray!30, radius=0.6}, copper/.style = {draw=orange!80,fill=orange!30, radius=0.2}]
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-6,-2) grid (0,2);

\foreach \x in {-1,-3,-5}
    {\node at (\x,0) [circle, draw, oxygen] (O\x0) {};}

\foreach \x in {-2,-4}
{
    \node at (\x,0) [circle, draw, copper] (Cu\x) {};
    \foreach \y in {1,-1}
    {\node at (\x,\y) [circle, draw, oxygen] (O\x\y) {};}
}

\draw [->, >=stealth, rotate=-45] ($(Cu-2) + (0,-0.35) $) -- ($(Cu-2) + (0,0.35) $);
\draw [->, >=stealth, rotate=135] ($(Cu-4) + (0,-0.35) $) -- ($(Cu-4) + (0,0.35) $);

\foreach \i in {-10, -30, -21, -2-1}
    {\draw[thick] (Cu-2) -- (O\i);}

\foreach \i in {-30, -50, -41, -4-1}
    {\draw[thick] (Cu-4) -- (O\i);}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

---

EDIT

This is my first (unelegant) attempt to create the second figure I need.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[oxygen/.style = {inner sep=2mm, draw=gray!80,fill=gray!30, radius=0.6}, copper/.style = {draw=orange!80,fill=orange!30, radius=0.2}]
\foreach \x [count=\i] in {1.25,2.75,5.25}
    {\node at (\x,0) [circle, draw, oxygen] (O\i0) {};}

\foreach \x in {2,4}
{
    \node[circle, draw, copper] (Cu\x) at (\x,0) {};
}    
\node at ($(Cu2) + (0,0.75)$) [circle, draw, oxygen] (O21) {};
\node at ($(Cu2) + (0,-0.75)$) [circle, draw, oxygen] (O2-1) {};
\node at ($(Cu4) + (0,1.25)$) [circle, draw, oxygen] (O41) {};
\node at ($(Cu4) + (0,-1.25)$) [circle, draw, oxygen] (O4-1) {};

\draw [->, >=stealth, rotate=-45] ($(Cu4) + (0,-0.35) $) -- ($(Cu4) + (0,0.35) $);
\draw [->, >=stealth, rotate=135] ($(Cu2) + (0,-0.35) $) -- ($(Cu2) + (0,0.35) $);

\foreach \i in {10,20, 21, 2-1}
    {\draw[thick] (Cu2) -- (O\i);}

\foreach \i in {20, 30, 41, 4-1}
    {\draw[thick] (Cu4) -- (O\i);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will the second figure be exactly like the first, except for the different distances?

Comment: Yes, only the distances change but still keeping the symmetry along the horizontal line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset
  {oxygen/.style =
    {circle, draw=gray!80, fill=gray!30, radius=0.6, inner sep=2mm},
   copper/.style =
    {circle, draw=orange!80, fill=orange!30, radius=0.2},
   bond/.style = {thick}
  }

% \oxygen{name}{position}
\newcommand\oxygen[2]%
  {\node[oxygen] (#1) at (#2) {};}

% \copper[direction of arrow]{name}{position}
% direction: <- (down), -> (up, default)
\newcommand\copper[3][]%
  {\node[copper] (#2) at (#3) {};
   \draw[->,>=stealth,#1] ($(#3)+(225:0.35)$) -- ($(#3)+(45:0.35)$);
  }

% \copox[direction of arrow]{name}{position}{distance Cu-O}
% name of nodes: (name), (name-0), (name-90), (name-180), (name-270)
\newcommand\copox[4][]%
  {\copper[#1]{#2}{#3}
   \foreach \a in {0,90,180,270}
     {\oxygen{#2-\a}{$(#2)+(\a:#4)$}
      \draw[bond] (#2) -- (#2-\a);
     }
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-6,-2) grid (3,2);
\copox[<-]{CO1}{-4,0}{1}
\copox{CO2}{-2,0}{1}
\copox[<-]{CO3}{0.5,0}{1.5}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]